# Add user input column to Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, user-input, interactive

I am trying to gather user input given a data set.  I want to insert a column where the user can determine whether they would want to own one of the cars in the `mtdata` set. This is completely subjective as opinions differ from person to person so I am not able to program this in.  Is there a way to append an extra column that can be a checkbox or dropdown menu to identify cars that a user would "Want to own?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

             titlePanel("Interesting Cars"),

             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 helpText("This is a side bar")),

               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("view")
               )
             )
           )),
         server = function(input, output) {

             output$view <- renderTable({
               head(mtcars[, 1:4], n = 6)

             })

           })
```

Comment: Are you just talking about filtering the data to what a user would want?

Comment: Potentially?  But, each item would have to be individually selected.  I'm not looking for data tables functionality, but rather user's opinions about a data set.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more of an example demonstrating what you mean with the `mtcars` dataset.  Give us an example of what you mean by defining 'interesting'.

Comment: It really is completely user subjective.  Instead of "interesting", I changed it to be would a user `want to own?` the car.

Comment: If the data were static, it'd be easy to put this into a google form, but the left hand nav will contain controls that will change the data that is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you can use the `DT` library.  By adding the `filter` option the user can define the different components one wants and see what cars come up.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Interesting Cars"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("This is a side bar")),

        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("view")
        )
    )
)),
server = function(input, output) {

    output$view <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(mtcars, 
                  filter = "top"
        )

    })

})
```

**Edit**

If it truly is so important to add another column indicating if it is 'interesting' there will be significantly more code to written if you intend to have users assign it on different conditions.  Here is an example with just the `mpg`.  The fundamental idea here is that you assign your data to the `reactiveValues` function.  It can then be modified as you like.  This can obviously be improved upon more (as it will continue to add columns) but it demonstrates the concept.

```
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Interesting Cars"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("This is a side bar"),
            uiOutput("mpg"),
            actionButton("add_label", "Mark Interesting")
            ),

        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("view")
        )
    )
)),
server = function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues(
        mydata = mtcars
        )

    output$mpg <- renderUI({
        numericInput("mpg_input", "MPG Cutoff?",
                     value = 15
                    )
    })

    output$view <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(values$mydata
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$add_label, {
        validate(
            need(!is.null(input$mpg_input), "need mpg value")
        )
        values$mydata <- data.frame(values$mydata,
                               Interesting_Flag = 
                                   ifelse(values$mydata$mpg > input$mpg_input,
                                      "Interesting",
                                      "Not Interesting"))
    })
})
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I'm looking to add an extra column where a user can input a Yes/No flag.

Comment: The `DT` package has the functionality of row selection (it can be used with the filter option if desired). It has pretty much the same effect of an extra column with checkboxes.

Comment: @user5029763 you are correct but the OP seems to want to have a physical column added given specific conditions.  I personally would also just use the filters and click on ones I would want.

Comment: @cdeterman Sorry, I might have expressed myself badly. The OP could use the row selection to keep track of the user's opinion with `input$table_rows_selected` and such.

Comment: @user5029763 you are correct, I would have provided that as an answer but the OP wants the new column added on.  If you'd like to provide an answer demonstrating `input$table_rows_selected` perhaps the OP may have other thoughts.

Comment: Right now it's a lil hard... I'm not on a computer hehe but as soon as I get to one I'll try :)

Comment: @cdeterman, im trying to have users review data quality...so, i want to essentially insert a column full of radioButtons where a reviewer can determine if the data is good or bad.